# Is it any safer to use POST instead of GET?

Tags: security, html

Is there any inherent "safety" with using POST instead of GET?  Example, if I have a page that is open to sql injection, does POST somehow keep me safer?  I know it won't make my code better, or fix my sql injection problem or any of that (just an example), but in general, can POST help a webpage be safer, regardless of what it does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POST will do *nothing* for security injection.

The only possible security consideration for POST over GET is that information won't be leaked in the HTTP referrer to sites that are linked to from the page.

It also means that the information won't be in your webserver logs, which can be a vector for finding potential exploits ... but it also means that they won't be available for debugging unless you take alternate measures for logging the values.

Answer (score 2):

## Not one bit.

POST just tells browsers and proxies that the request is not idempotent.  (and therefore should not be sent again)